# Duplicate resources google_app_id google_app_key

Tags: android, firebase, ionic3, cordova-plugins

ionic v3
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase@0.1.24 --save

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
[string/google_app_id] C:\Users\Asus\Desktop--\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml [string/google_app_id] C:\Users\Asus\Desktop--\platforms\android\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values\values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
[string/google_api_key] C:\Users\Asus\Desktop--\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml [string/google_api_key] C:\Users\Asus\Desktop-\platfo-rms\android\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values\values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources

here's my build.gradle: app (androidx)
.
.

> dependencies { implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
>
> if (cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference('GradlePluginKotlinEnabled',
> 'false').toBoolean()) {
> implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version" }
>
> // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START implementation(project(path:
> ":CordovaLib")) implementation
> "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0" implementation
> "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.+" implementation
> "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.+" implementation
> "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.+" implementation
> "androidx.core:core:1.6.+" implementation
> "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22@aar" implementation
> "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0" implementation
> "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0" implementation
> "com.google.gms:google-services:+" implementation
> "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+" implementation
> "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+" implementation
> "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+" implementation
> "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+" implementation
> "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+" // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES
> END }

i have tried to delete both on android.json but still got the same problem?
the problem accured when i add cordova-plugin-firebase
google-services and firebase plugin provide both google_app_id and google_app_key
any help will be appreciated!

Comment: did you find the solution. please let me know i am stuck with this problem i also tried delete two files but same error